# socket.io store socket in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to refresh a html page via socket.io. Therefore I want to call the refresh function after changes on the server side. At the moment I do this just with a test. But at the moment I have no idea how I can **access the socket outside** the **io.on('connection' ...**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var clientSocket;

module.exports.startConnection = function () {
    io.on('connection', function (socket){
        clientSocket = socket;
    });

    http.listen(8001, function (){
        console.log('listening on *:8001');
    });
};


module.exports.refresh = function () {
    clientSocket.emit('refresh');
};
```

Test:

```
const refreshDashboard = require('../src/func/refreshDashboard.js');
refreshDashboard.startConnection();
refreshDashboard.refresh();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error message: clientSocket.emit('refresh');
               
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined**

Comment: You are assigning clientSocker on connection event. Are you sure that the connection event handler is getting called?

Comment: Yes. The startConnection function works and connects with the client. If I use the .emit('refresh') inside io.on('connection' ... it also works.

Comment: Your attempted server design seems to assume that there is only ever one client connected to your server.  That is usually a wrong design.  Servers typically handle connections to many, many clients and thus it never works to store one client's socket in a module level variable.

Comment: You will probably need to back up several steps and describe the problem you're actually trying to solve because you need a different design approach.  When you want to send the `refresh` event, do you want to send it to all connected clients?  Or just to one? To send to all, you can do `io.emit('refresh')`.   If just to one, how do you know which client you want to send it to (keeping mind there may be thousands of connected clients)?